# Finding Variance from Mean

Tags: expectation, variance

$$ E[X] = NQ $$

$$ X = \sum_{i=1}^N y_i^2$$

where $y_i$~$N(0,Q)$  and they are independent.

$$What \space is \space Var(X) ?$$

My understanding is:

$$ Var(X) = E[X^2]-E[X]^2 $$
But then what is $E[X^2]$ ?

I understand $X^2 = [ \space\sum_{i=1}^N y_i^2 \space ]^2$
But how do I compute $E[X^2] \space ?$

Comment: You multiply it out and use linearity of expectation. Thanks to independence, the only new quantity you need to compute is $E(y^4).$ $X$ is $Q$ times a chi squared variable, so you can look up the correct answer that way.

Comment: How is X = Q * ChiSquared? 
ChiSquared is sum of standard normals squared so then E[X] would be Q*E[ChiSquared] = 0 since E[ChiSquared] = 0.
Which is not correct as I said in the question E[X] = NQ.

Comment: Chi squared is the sum of *squares* of standard normals, so the expectation is $n,$ not zero, as you can see on e.g. the Wikipedia sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a typo. Since $X=Q^2\chi^2$, the first line should read
$$E[X]=NQ^2$$
by using the expectation of a $\chi^2$ distribution. To find the variance, use the variance of the $\chi^2$ distribution:
$$V[X]=V[Q^2\chi^2]=Q^4V[\chi^2]=2NQ^4$$